# How to choose one of the class words using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am developing a project to **scrape** data from a page, I came to a problem when trying to **scrape** not the data itself, but the class name, since it's used to set the rating of the books at this address https://books.toscrape.com/

When I get the data, it came like this

```
{'class': ['star-rating', 'Three']}
{'class': ['star-rating', 'One']}
{'class': ['star-rating', 'One']}
{'class': ['star-rating', 'Four']}
```

which is a dictionary, but I am only interested in the last entry, I will save it to the database later and will check those ones with high rating.

How to ignore star-rating and only store in the list those last words?

PS - This is the loop I am using to get that result

```
for content in contents:
    title = content.find('h3').text
    price = content.find('p', class_='price_color').text
    rating = content.find('p').attrs
```

This is the way the HTML is set

```
<p class="star-rating Three">
 <i class="icon-star"></i>
 <i class="icon-star"></i>
 <i class="icon-star"></i>
 <i class="icon-star"></i>
 <i class="icon-star"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: Could you share the code you use for scraping to get the above result?

Comment: @user696969 I just edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just get those last words from the list? Like:

```
data['class'][1]
```

Or, to ensure to get the last one:

```
data['class'][-1]
```

Comment: let me try that... will past here what I got

Answer (score 3):

tks a lot Alberto Pirillo, you pointed me to the correct direction and after some searching for dictionaries.. I solved with your advice..

it was like this `rating['class'][1]`
Now its returning just the last word

```
Three
One
One
Four
Five
```

Thanks a lot folks